# Windows XP SP3 install keeps rebooting

Tags: windows, windows-xp, installation

The base fonts on my Windows XP Pro were corrupted.
A suggested fix was to "install" XP again, essentially just to overwrite the WINNT folder hence resetting all the fonts.

I downloaded the XP Pro SP3 installer from our corporate MSDN account, ran it straight from the HDD and at the very end it crashed and rebooted.  Now it just keeps rebooting over and over after saying "Continuing installation...."

I can't boot in Safe Mode, I can't get to a command prompt or anything.  I'm out of ideas.

Formatting the drive and performing a fresh install is NOT an option.

Comment: Would attempting another re-install be an option? I'm curious why format/install isn't an option. Do you not have backups?

Comment: Attempting another re-install would be an option, just have to wait until tomorrow when I can pick up a blank CD.  I have backups of almost everything except I had just finished a huge project document that I can't afford to lose and didn't back up before attempting my re-install.

Comment: If you need to recover a specific file without addressing the corrupt OS, you may be best off booting from a live CD, such as [slax](http://www.slax.org/), and copying the file(s) to either a USB thumbdrive or network storage.

Comment: Just do a repair install of Windows from the CD.

Answer (score 0):

Could just use a live version of linux ie Ubuntu and upoload the file or save it to a usb 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

Answer (score 0):

Revert to a backup and try another method to fix the font problem. This method is obviously going to be more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing how your stuff became corrupted in the first place, I have many times seen different kind of this error.

It might be a long shot, but it has helped me a couple of times.

Download HDAT2 (http://www.hdat2.com), a free hard drive regenerating program, designed to fix bad sectores. Burn it to a CD, and follow the instructions to repair your HDD.

Even tho it's just 10 bad sectors out of millions it can cause this kind of problems.

I know it seems a little "out of context" but trust me, I've had it work for me.

Regards,

Patrick Jørgensen